# OOMD - Is there a need of showing database connection in UML Class diagram? (A simple login diagram)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

I want to design a class diagram of a simple login operation. Use case is:

1. User enters id and pin
2. System checks login info.

So, I decided to create a controller for the user (`UserHandler`) and a user class (`User`). UserHandler takes id and pin and checks that they are valid with a method ( `isUserValid()` ).  

In my opinion, a class should not include all database records for only one of them. I mean there should not be a list of users to check whether login info is correct or not. This is a simple operation with just a requirement of connecting to database. 

My question is how can I show that `isUserValid()` method is connecting to the database? Is there a need of showing this connection? 

Or should I create a `userList` in `UserHandler` and keep all the users in that list? 

Any help will be very appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create an `Authorization` class that takes a user name/password to authorize. This `Authorization` class will look into the users database. You could model this as association with multiplicity.

[image]

Comment: `Authorization` class "authorizes" (association) `User` class means that  `Authorization` class connects to the database, searches **all** users and validates the user?

Comment: See the added picture.